# apache virtual host multiple directories

Tags: php, apache, alias, virtualhost

I have setup a virtual host in apache with multiple directories for www.abc.com and abc.com/api which I need to points towards different directory

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
            DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/api/"
            ServerName www.abc.com
            ServerAlias www.abc.com
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            # Other directives here
            # Other directives here
            Alias /api/ "/var/www/html/public/"

            <Directory "/var/www/html/public">

            </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
```

Its working when I go to www.abc.com/api/ but when I move beyond that www.abc.com/api/v1/ I got the error
Not Found

The requested URL /var/www/html/public/index.php was not found on this server.

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using an *MVC framework*. If that's the case you need to configure your routing path in order to access your desired file.

Comment: Yes I'm using Laravel 5, but the path I'm making is exist in laravel route file and can be access via different virtual host like www.xyz.com/api/v1/ from same location, issue seems to be when I try to access it via same domain name through apache Alias.